# How to hide a custom toolbar from IE

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have developed a toolbar with one button for IE.
My toolbar displays with a default close button in the IE window.
When I click on the close button the toolbar prompts for the disable option.
This completely disables the toolbar.

But what I need is I just want to hide the toolbar. So still it can perform some actions even though the toolbar is not visible.

How can I make the toolbar just to hide instead of disable?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried any IE statements? There are a few for JS a[Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Comment: I created the toolbar with C++ ATL. I would like to know how I can handle it in my ATL project.